# How can I configure java.library.path at runtime?

Tags: java, java.library.path

In my project I need to configure java.library.path at runtime. Does Java gives me such ability?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First option is to set java.library.path to different value

```
/**
 * Sets the java library path to the specified path
 *
 * @param path the new library path
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static void setLibraryPath(String path) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("java.library.path", path);

    //set sys_paths to null
    final Field sysPathsField = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
    sysPathsField.setAccessible(true);
    sysPathsField.set(null, null);
}
```

The second option is to append your path to java.library.path

```
/**
* Adds the specified path to the java library path
*
* @param pathToAdd the path to add
* @throws Exception
*/
public static void addLibraryPath(String pathToAdd) throws Exception{
    final Field usrPathsField = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("usr_paths");
    usrPathsField.setAccessible(true);

    //get array of paths
    final String[] paths = (String[])usrPathsField.get(null);

    //check if the path to add is already present
    for(String path : paths) {
        if(path.equals(pathToAdd)) {
            return;
        }
    }

    //add the new path
    final String[] newPaths = Arrays.copyOf(paths, paths.length + 1);
    newPaths[newPaths.length-1] = pathToAdd;
    usrPathsField.set(null, newPaths);
}
```

Taken from [fahd.blog](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2011/08/changing-java-library-path-at-runtime.html)

Comment: Why posting a question and an answer at the same time? If this solves your problem, please simply remove your question.

Comment: Better ask why StackOverflow gives such possibility to answer my question myself :)